# Delete element from double linked list in c

Tags: c, arrays, list, malloc

I have a double linked list, here's structure I used:

```
struct list_el{
    struct data* val;
    struct list_el* next;
    struct list_el* prev;
};

struct list{
    struct list_el* head;
    struct list_el* tail;
};
```

When I do it like this, everything works correctly, insert and delete functions are working as I wanted:

```
int main(){
    struct data d1 = {"Name1","Surname1"};
    struct data d2 = {"Name2","Surname2"};
    struct data d3 = {"Name3","Surname3"};
    struct data d4 = {"Name4","Surname4"};
    struct list *l = create();
    struct list_el *el1, *el2, *el3, *el4;
    el1 = create_elem(&d1);
    el2 = create_elem(&d2);
    el3 = create_elem(&d3);
    el4 = create_elem(&d4);
    insert (l, el1);
    insert (l, el2);
    insert (l, el3);
    insert (l, el4);
    del_el(l, el1);
}
```

The problem is when I want to do it on arrays:

```
struct data arr_data[4]={{"Name1","Surname1"},{"Name2","Surname2"},{"Name3","Surname3"},{"Name4","Surname4"}};

struct list_el arr_el[4];

int main(){    
    struct list *l = create_l();
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
         arr_el[i] = *create_elem(&arr_data[i]);
         insert_l(l, &arr_el[i]);
    }   
    //Till now everythink works correctly

    //Here's the problem
    del_el(l, &arr_el[0]);
}
```

When I run it it shows me an error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x10002dfb0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Don't know why it happened. In `create_elem()` I use `malloc`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to free one of the elements of `arr_el`.  These were **not** allocated by `malloc`, so you can't free them.

What you're doing is dereferencing the pointer returned by `create_elem` and *copying* the values it contains into an element of `arr_el`.  This also means you have a memory leak.

You should instead declare `arr_el` as an array of *pointers*:

```
struct list_el *arr_el[4];
```

Then you assign the return value of `create_elem` directly to one of these:

```
arr_el[i] = create_elem(&arr_data[i]);
insert_l(l, arr_el[i]);
```

And you can then subsequently delete them:

```
del_el(l, arr_el[0]);
```